# Check a date field is blank or empty in MS Flow expression

Tags: power-automate

As part of an email step in our Flow, we are creating an HTML table, where certain rows are hidden using css.

So our expression formula (in the body of the *Outlook - Send an email from a Shared Mailbox* step looks like this:

```
if(
And(
    Or(
        equals(triggerBody()['DD_Artwork']['Value'], 'Bargain New Store')
        , equals(triggerBody()['DD_Artwork']['Value'], 'Home & Fashion')
        ,equals(triggerBody()['DD_Artwork']['Value'], 'Home Store'))
    , @empty(triggerBody()?['StoreOpeningDate']))
,'tr.StoreOpenDate {display:visible}', 'tr.StoreOpenDate {display:none}')
```

this part, checking the Date Selector field StoreOpeningDate is not working:

```
, @empty(triggerBody()?['StoreOpeningDate']))
```

we have also tried:

```
, Not IsBlank(triggerBody()?['StoreOpeningDate']))
```

and

```
, Not IsEmpty(triggerBody()?['StoreOpeningDate']))
```

and even:

```
, Not equals(triggerBody()?['StoreOpeningDate']), '')
```

but we always get the error message **The expression is invalid**

so what's the right way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced a similar problem. The `TriggerBody()` function is doing the damage. Just use
`Empty(item()?['DateField'])` not equal to false in the condition.

Comment: Sorry, but above didnt work. Using field name, apply not equal to and Null expression on right side worked.